# acceptdragdrop in flex

Tags: apache-flex

I am having one mxml in which I am doing dodrag of buttons into other canvas I want to have acceptdragdrop in other file so that the canvas accepts dragged buttons

there is Panel.mxml in which I am writing

```
this.addChild(button);
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,dragTaskImage)

private function dragTaskImage(event:MouseEvent):void
{

.....

}
```

Now I want to have other function in workflow.mxml in which I accept drag?

Answer (score 0):

There are several good examples and tutorials out there on drag and drop for Flex. Take a look at:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf64595-7fed.html

http://www.flexafterdark.com/tutorials/Flex-Drag-and-Drop

http://www.truespire.com/examples/dual-list-manager/

http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/09/19/dragging-rows-between-two-different-flex-datagrid-controls/